# Python KMax Pooling (MXNet)

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, mxnet

I'm trying to recreate the char-level CNN in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01781v1.pdf) and am a bit stuck at the final step where I need to create a k-max pooling layer, because I am using MXNet and it does not have this.

> An important difference is also the introduction of multiple temporal
>   k-max pooling layers. This allows to detect the k most important
>   features in a sentence, independent of their specific position,
>   preserving their relative order.

However, MXNet does have the ability to [add a new-op](http://mxnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_to/new_op.html) which I have been trying to do like so (although getting a bit confused with the shape of the data, given filters and batch-size).

The shape of the data coming in:

```
128 (min-batch) x 512 (number of filters) x 1 (height) x 125 (width)
```

The shape of the data coming out (k-max pooling, k = 7):

```
128 (min-batch) x 512 (number of filters) x 1 (height)  x 7 (width)
```

My idea so far ... :

```
class KMaxPooling(mx.operator.CustomOp):
    def forward(self, is_train, req, in_data, out_data, aux):
        # Desired (k=3):
        # in_data = np.array([1, 2, 4, 10, 5, 3])
        # out_data = [4, 10, 5]
        x = in_data[0].asnumpy()
        idx = x.argsort()[-k:]
        idx.sort(axis=0)
        y = x[idx]
```

However, I'm not sure about several things:

1. How to test whether this works (once I have some complete code)
2. What the dimensions should be? I'm sorting on the last dimension (axis=0)
3. What to do for the backward() function i.e. the gradient propogation
4. Whether this will work with GPU - I'm guessing I will have to rewrite it in C/cuda?

I found this example by someone else for keras (but don't have the rep to link):

```
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as T
from keras.layers.core import MaskedLayer

class KMaxPooling(MaskedLayer):
    def __init__(self, pooling_size):
        super(MaskedLayer, self).__init__()
        self.pooling_size = pooling_size
        self.input = T.tensor3()

    def get_output_mask(self, train=False):
        return None

    def get_output(self, train=False):
        data = self.get_input(train)
        mask = self.get_input_mask(train)

        if mask is None:
            mask = T.sum(T.ones_like(data), axis=-1)
        mask = mask.dimshuffle(0, 1, "x")

        masked_data = T.switch(T.eq(mask, 0), -np.inf, data)

        result = masked_data[T.arange(masked_data.shape[0]).dimshuffle(0, "x", "x"),
                             T.sort(T.argsort(masked_data, axis=1)[:, -self.pooling_size:, :], axis=1),
                             T.arange(masked_data.shape[2]).dimshuffle("x", "x", 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is no KMaxPooling support in Mxnet so far, and it could be tricky to implement it. Yet, I can think of some tips to help you, if you decide implementing it:

1. If you use Gluon, then you can implement KMaxPooling as a HybridBlock and then use [HybridSequential](http://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter07_distributed-learning/hybridize.html#HybridSequential) to run it. As long as you use functions from the provided as an argument "F"-backend (avoid using numpy), you will be able to run your code on GPU. So, you don't need to do C++.
2. Using HybridBlock and functions from "F"-backend only will also solve the problem of the backward propagation. You basically won't need to write it, because Autograd will do it for you.
3. With HybridBlock you can debug your code easier. You just don't call net.hybridize() method, and you get "nd"-backend, which is slower than "sym"-backend, but allows you to use a debugger.
4. As for dimensions, if you notice there are different version of MaxPool block in Gluon: MaxPool1D, MaxPool2D, MaxPool3D. You can implement only 1 KMaxPool1D for your case. You will then stack the output of KMaxPool1D as if multiple filters were applied, essentially adding values to the end of the "z"-dimension.

Hope that helps.